# Difference between Wallet Sync and Daemon Sync

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

What is the difference between Wallet Synchronization and Daemon Synchronization, in case of using either of local node or remote node?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Daemon status is how synced it's blockchain is. Wallet status is how many blocks are scanned.

A daemon *syncs* blocks, a wallet *scans* blocks for incoming transfers.